# Indentation in C cs50 style Mario pyramid

Tags: c, indentation, cs50

I recently started Harvard cs50 (I'm a beginner) and I've completed the first Mario problem.

I have some issues with indentation style and when I type style50 mario.c it keeps saying I need to add or remove lines and spaces. I don't really understand how to do improve the style.

Can anybody help me with this?

This is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int h;

  do

  {  

    // ask user to input height 
    h = get_int("Height: ");
  }

  while (h < 1 || h > 8);

  for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
  {

// hashes and blankspaces

      for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)

  { 
        if (i + j < h - 1)

        printf(" ");

      else

        printf("#");

      }

      printf("\n");

   }

}
```

Comment: Choose an indentation style, then go through the code as though you were writing it and reformat it to use the style of your choice. (There are automated tools for this, but I suppose the point here is to learn to do it yourself so that when you write your own code it will also follow it.) You can make the choice of style by looking at some properly indented code that you like and find readable, e.g., proper code in the course's examples (presumably not all of them are exercises in how to fix it). Or pick from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style

Comment: Even a half decent text editor will help in indentation. Never use Windows Notepad for coding. On style, you should not use double line-spacing for code, it makes it harder to read. Just leave a blank line to separate the code sections.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the link given from style50 or submit50 where it will say specifically which lines should be indented or unindented.

The class's style rubric is shown here: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/style/c/
If you pick a different style as suggested by others, then you would still be failing the style50 grading.  The CS50 style demands four spaces (I just use tab) and it appears that yours are of varying lengths.  Also the body of your if and for statements should be more indented than the if or for part.

Answer (score 1):

You can skim [this](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/style/c/) page and figure it out very quickly. What I noticed in your code is that `int h;` is not indented, also the comment `// hashes and blankspaces` is also not indented, and the `{` for the inner loop is not indented, also the `if` statement doesn't have `{` and `}` which I think is expected by `style50` and the line inside the if statement is also not indented. Also the `if` statement is not in line with the `else` statement. Also, `style50` I think expect a 4 spaces indentation but yours looks like only 2 spaces.